# Can't return nullptr to my class C++

Tags: c++, null, nullptr

In my method in my class, I'm checking if a value is 0 to return `nullptr`, however I can't seem to do that.

```
Complex Complex::sqrt(const Complex& cmplx) {
    if(cmplx._imag == 0)
        return nullptr;

    return Complex();
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `could not convert 'nullptr' from 'std::nullptr_t' to 'Complex'`

I realize now, that `nullptr` is for pointers, however, my object is not a pointer, is there a way for me to set it to null or something similar?

Comment: Set the return type to Complex*

Comment: maybe because you are not returning a pointer here. You want Complex* not Complex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are returning `Complex`, which is not a pointer. In order to return `nullptr`, your return type should be `Complex*`.

Noticed your edit - here's what you can do:

```
bool Complex::sqrt(const Complex& cmplx, Complex& out) {
    if(cmplx._imag == 0)
    {
        // out won't be set here!
        return false;
    }

    out = Complex(...); // set your out parameter here
    return true;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Complex resultOfSqrt;
if(sqrt(..., resultOfSqrt))
{ 
    // resultOfSqrt is guaranteed to be set here
} 
else
{
    // resultOfSqrt wasn't set
}
```

Comment: Agree with this method. You don't have to worry about leaking memory and won't need to add in boost.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as the error states, `nullptr` is not convertible to your type `Complex`.  What you can do is (a) return a `Complex*` (or better yet, a smart pointer), and test for `nullptr` to see whether the function had a non-trivial result or perhaps (b) use a library like [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) to design your function in such a way that it might not have a valid object to return.

In fact, Boost.Optional's documentation even gives the example of a `double sqrt(double n)` function, which shouldn't be defined for negative `n` and is similar to your example.  If you can use Boost, an example would be like

```
boost::optional<Complex> Complex::sqrt(const Complex& cmplx) 
{
    if (cmplx._imag == 0)
        // Uninitialized value.
        return boost::optional<Complex>();

    // Or, do some computations.
    return boost::optional<Complex>(some parameters here);
}
```

Some [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360706/when-to-use-boostoptional-and-when-to-use-stdunique-ptr-in-cases-when-you-wa) that might be helpful.