# Indirect Member RAII: unique_ptr or optional?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, raii, boost-optional

Consider a class with a member that can't be stored directly, e.g., because it does not have a default constructor, and the enclosing class's constructor doesn't have enough information to create it:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(){} // Default ctor
private:
    /* Won't build: no default ctor or way to call it's 
        non-default ctor at Foo's ctor. */
    Bar m_bar; 
};
```

Clearly, `m_bar` needs to be stored differently, e.g., through a pointer. A [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) seems better, though, as it will destruct it automatically:

```
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_bar;
```

It's also possible to use [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional), though:

```
    std::experimenatl::optional<Bar> m_bar;
```

My questions are: 1. What are the tradeoffs? and 2. Does it make sense to build a class automating the choice between them?

Specifically, looking at the [exception guarantees for the ctor of `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) and the [exception guarantees for the ctor of `std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional/optional), it seems clear that the former must perform dynamic allocation and deallocation - runtime speed disadvantages, and the latter stores things in some (aligned) memory buffer - size disadvantages. Are these the only tradeoffs?

If these are indeed the tradeoffs, and given that both types share enough of their interface (ctor, `operator*`), does it make sense to automate the choice between them with something like

```
 template<typename T>
 using indirect_raii = typename std::conditional<
     // 20 - arbitrary constant
     sizeof(std::experimental::optional<T>) > 
         20 + sizeof(std::exerimental::optional<T>)sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T>),
     std::unique_ptr<T>,
     std::experimental::optional<T>>::type;
```

(Note: there is a [question discussing the tradeoffs between these two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360706/when-to-use-boostoptional-and-when-to-use-stdunique-ptr-in-cases-when-you-wa)  as return types, but the question and answers focus on what each conveys to the callers of the function, which is irrelevant for these private members.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there are other trade-offs at play here:

- `unique_ptr` is not copyable or copy-assignable, while `optional` is.
  I suppose one thing you could do is make `indirect_RAII` a class-type and conditionally add definitions to make it copyable by calling `Bar`'s copy ctor, even when `unique_ptr` is selected. (Or conversely, disable copying when it's an optional.)
- `optional` types can have a `constexpr` constructor -- you can't really do the equivalent thing with a `unique_ptr` at compile-time.
- `Bar` can be incomplete at the time that `unique_ptr<Bar>` is constructed. It cannot be incomplete at the time that `optional<Bar>` is known. In your example I guess you assume that `Bar` is complete since you take its size, but potentially you might want to implement a class using `indirect_RAII` where this isn't the case.
- Even in cases where `Bar` is large, you still may find that e.g. `std::vector<Foo>` will perform better when `optional` is selected than when `unique_ptr` is. I would expect this to happen in cases where the `vector` is populated once, and then iterated over many times.

It may be that as a general rule of thumb, your size rule is good for common use in your program, but I guess for "common use" it doesn't really matter which one you pick. An alternative to using your `indirect_RAII` type is, just pick one or the other in each case, and in places where you would have taken advantage of the "generic interface", pass the type as a template parameter when necessary. And in performance-critical areas, make the appropriate choice manually.

Comment: Thanks. For your first point, I guess that `shared_ptr` is a contender too, then?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that also at first, but then the semantics fundamentally changes, right? Since it doesn't copy the underlying data. If you are only using it with `const` types then I guess it's ok. But you don't want to e.g. add another data member to your class, and suddenly some other part of the program switches over to `shared_ptr` from `optional` and breaks some code.